# Task.WhenAny throttling efficiency

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I was recently reading through some documentation for using TAP, specifically [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx#Using%20the%20Built-in%20Task-based%20Combinators) under the smaller heading "Task.WhenAny." They state 4 primary purposes for the Task.WhenAny:

- Redundancy
- Interleaving
- Throttling
- Early bailout

Underneath the interleaving (and indirectly the throttling) subsection they have this code

```
List<Task<Bitmap>> imageTasks = 
(from imageUrl in urls select GetBitmapAsync(imageUrl)).ToList();
while(imageTasks.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        Task<Bitmap> imageTask = await Task.WhenAny(imageTasks);
        imageTasks.Remove(imageTask);

        Bitmap image = await imageTask;
        panel.AddImage(image);
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Wouldn't this code be pretty inefficient? I am under the assumption that once Task.WhenAll's first task completes it then sets the other tasks in the list to "RanToCompletion" or "Cancelled" or some other status that would kill the progress of the other tasks. So even if it was only 2 tasks in the list to download images as in this example and 1 image was 2MB and the other one 4MB, more than likely the 2MB image would finish first (and 2ish MB or the other one would be received). It would then remove the  2MB from the list and start the loop over. Which seems like it would then start the 4MB download again, essentially wasting the progress already made, correct??

Comment: Why don't you write a code  to test your assumption? which is I generally do to understand the details of some concepts....

Comment: `WhenAny` will have a Result of one of the completed tasks provided in the collection, it won't set all tasks to cancelled or completed. Once it performs the image operation it will then repeat the loop and get the next image to add. `WhenAll` on the other hand will return a task that will be completed only when the specified tasks are completed.

Comment: You can always use TPL DataFlow, which includes features like **throttling**.  Also, TPL's pipeline features arguably better serves what the intent of the code above is trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All image downloads are executed in parallel at the same time in the instant you call 'GetBitmapAsync'.

The loop just checks which ones are done and add them to the panel. This way you can see the images as soon as they arrived.

Once a task ends, it does not affect the status of the other tasks.

Comment: And this is because a task will not be re-run because a task will only run if if it in the Created status. When it's in any other status it wont run, but return it's current status right?

Comment: Although you can create tasks, most of the time a task represents something already in motion, something that is being executed, so once it is done you cannot execute it again using that task, you need to create other that represent another execution of the same operation.